# Motherboard HDDPWR1 connector

Tags: hard-drive, sata, power-supply

I need help identifying the name of a connector.

I have a Gateway DX4870-UB318 computer, I opened the case and wanted to attach another hard drive, but to my surprise one existing SATA hard drive was connected to the motherboard with this connector:

[image]

And here is the spot on the Motherboard where the power was supplied.

[image]

What is the name of this adapter and where can I get another one?

**Clues:**

This computer was bought new October 2013 from best buy, box number: DX4870-UB318.  The gateway folks won't divulge the type of motherboard it has nor give specs on it.

On the wire itself is an identification code: `H.35090NJ01-000`

Next to the connector on the motherboard it says: HDDPWR1 and the second one says HDDPWR2.  This cable has two SATA power connectors and one mystery connector.

The power supply has no molex power cables and no SATA power connectors!  This is the most bizarre hard drive power system I've seen.  I guess the motherboard folks are trying to remove the burden for desktop power supplies to provide adapters (molex, SATA, other) to CD's and hard drives.

Can someone put a name on that white flat 6 pin HDD Power Connector?

**My Solution**

I ended up running out to TigerDirect store buying a "SATA Power Y Splitter Cable" to provide more spaces to power SATA devices.

Comment: Is this just for the power? It sounds like a slimline 9-pin power cable.

Comment: This proprietary PSU and proprietary motherboard cannot be upgraded.  It was designed to be non-upgradable on purpose.  Check out an embarassing "one-star" list of amazon reviews ranting about about this: http://www.amazon.com/Acer-Aspire-AT3-605-UR21-Desktop-Black/product-reviews/B00COGA69S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats apparently a  3.96mm pitch crimp power connector. I can't seem to find any reasonably priced, and in stock things that convert that to sata. In theory, you could then build an adaptor off that, or you know what you're looking for.

(google trail from [here](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=HDDPWR1) to [here](http://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CHkQFjAJ&url=http://www.bwi.com/document/17746&ei=n5yeUqCNEcfqkAWM-IDQCw&usg=AFQjCNH1z4QAgDYwDUu4q8WGxUF7eP26EA&sig2=8gHJqI4-gO-Ui-Bc9yDaGg&bvm=bv.57155469,d.dGI&cad=rja) then from [here](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=Output%20Power%20for%20Hard%20Disk%20%283.96mm%29) to [here](http://www.yiyief.com/product/listbypdf.asp?id=116)

That said, replacing the PSU for a standard *sane* PSU would be a great idea. Most OEM PSUs arn't great and yours seems horribly crippled.

Answer (score 3):

FIRST AND FOREMOST * * * UPGRADE THE PSU * * *

1. Above all else, I would advise you to immediately replace this low-quality power supply, with a high-quality power supply. Go with a well-reviewed model from Antec, Corsair, Enermax, Seasonic, XFX, etc. of 350 watts or more, taking into account any planned upgrades for the PC, especially possible addition of a dedicated video/graphics card. (If short of funds, even a good used older model would be preferable to leaving a bad apple in your machine.)

   At this quality level of power supply, I would not be surprised if the power supply were to fail right around the time the warranty expires (or sooner under heavy use). And when cheap power supplies fail, it is not unknown for the other components of the system to be damaged along with the power supply.
2. I recommend powering your hard drives, optical drives and any graphics/video card *directly* from the wiring harness of your new PSU, not from the motherboard; the motherboard's job should not be to transport power to other components.
3. Here is one way to go about upgrading the PSU:

   A. Remove the Gateway 12-pin connector from the Gateway PSU, along with about 8" of the factory-attached wiring set. 
   Or -- if you want to keep stock PSU intact -- find another similar-style 12-pin connector (from eBay, Fry's, online parts vendor, old donor PSU), a dozen 8"-lengths of 16awg UL1007 hook-up wire (eBay, Fry's, online parts vendor, old donor PSU), and join your new 12-pin to your new wire-set.

   B. Get a 24-pin female ATX connector [from eBay, Fry's, online parts vendor] and wire it onto the open end of the 8" wire-set (that you just removed -- or manufactured -- in step A above). This needs to be done thoughtfully and correctly. Check out the closely-related links I've included [below]. Now you have a double-ended adapter that has a 24-pin female on one end, and the 12-pin male on the other end

   C. Plug that adapter onto the standard 24-pin male connector of your new PSU.

   D. Install the new PSU. You may have to get creative in how you fit/screw/secure the PSU box to the case, depending on how the standard ATX form factor of your new PSU compares to the form factor of the stock Gateway PSU.

(When you are finished, you may wish to send before and after photos with refurbishing commentary to Acer's "Design and Marketing Team for the Gateway DX4870-UB318 computer", if you can find the appropriate mailing address.)

---

I recommend taking a close look at these related links:

http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1833076/odd-motherboard-power-connector.html

http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/id-2004597/gateway-dx4885-ub3a-desktop-compact-motherboard-microatx-motherboard.html

http://www.ebay.com/itm/Acer-motherboard-12-pin-cable-adaptor-to-24-pin-Use-larger-power-supplies-/161185245004?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item258763a74c

Answer (score 2):

This is surely a "Needlessly Proprietary SATA Power Cable". They are known for causing surprise and disappointment upon opening the case of the machine. They can only be ordered painfully from the manufacturer.

You have two options:

1. I would use an SATA Power Y Splitter Cable. This will run you $5~10
   shipped.
2. You can also use an adapter that converts a 4 Pins Molex to a 15pin Serial ATA power adapter (if you have any of those available).

Pick one of those and forget about that nasty looking cable :)

Comment: The system I have is bizarre, the power supply has no molex or sata output.  The CD/DVD and the single HD are powered from this one HDDPWR1 port shown above.  Do you think it's a good idea to put a splitter on that and put the CD and two hard drives on that one mystery proprietary gateway port?  I never thought it possible a power supply have no molex or sata power output.

Comment: I would connect an SATA Y-adapter to the end of the proprietary cable that currently plugs into your drive.

Just for kicks, I tried to find a way to order *any* parts for your computer from Gateway... Don't bother.

Comment: heh, at this point, assuming its a standard atx power supply, the sensible thing might be to replace the power supply to a standard one.

Answer (score 1):

This power supply:

[image]

```
FSP Group Inc.
Model NO FSP300-40AABA
AC INPUT 100-127/220-240V-,7/3.5A,60/50Hz
```

Send this power supply back to the store if you can.  Bad business practices must be punished!

Why?  It has zero molex or SATA power connectors!  The Power supply has a single proprietary cable that goes between the power supply and motherboard.  It has a single propriatary cable that translates the (3.96mm pitch crimp power connector) from the motherboard to a single SATA for the CD/DVD and 1 Hard drive.

You're going to need to go through the manufacturers website and pay 1000x exorbitant prices for their proprietary cable.  Or buy a SATA splitter.  BAD manufacturer.  NO biscuit.

I ended up going to a hard drive Y splitter power cable from a computer parts store.  I let the hard drive just hang in there.

Comment: wait, the motherboard cable is proprietary as well? I'm wondering why they even bothered with a full sized PSU/mini tower case then. It seems to be very similar to http://www.amazon.com/Acer-Aspire-AT3-605-UR21-Desktop-Black/product-reviews/B00COGA69S . This seems to be a horrible system to maintain

Answer (score 1):

I have this same problem - found the a 500 watt replacement on ebay 231267206305 for $99. Appears to be the exact replacement.  I think it should be a good one since it is 80 gold rated.

Anyways my oldest son is going to buy it and upgrade his unit to a newer Geforce model. Will report back.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old thread, but I found it really helpful, although some of the info is a little off.
The small white connector the OP shows is known as JST XH 2.54mm
You can get them online with wires pre installed. I got a set of these white plugs and a SATA power extension cable (15 pin)
Cut the end I needed off the sata extension and soldered it to the little white plug, heat shrink the connections and you've got whatever power adapter you need. It won't deliver a lot of power of course, it's off the motherboard, but enough for sata drives or a lower power peripheral. I'm running my 3rd party fan controller off it.

Further info, that little plug on the motherboard delivers 2x+5V red, 2xnegative black, 2x+12v yellow.
Make certain you get the wires in the correct order!